# Express and React running on same port - how can I use Routing?

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express, react-router, react-router-dom

Currently I serve my react-files in a static way by serving the files in my express-server:

```js
app.use(express.static(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "build")));
app.get("/", function (req, res) {
  res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "build", "index.html"));
});

app.use(cors());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({ limit: "10mb", extended: false }));
app.use(bodyParser.json({ limit: "10mb", extended: false }));
```

This works fine and I am able to access my page, send requests, etc.

Now I want to implement React-Routing as it is tedious to completely leave my site when I go back once. Although I tried really hard so far, I was not able to find a solution, because as soon as I access `localhost:3000/home` for example I get the error, that I can not use GET, because it instantly refers to my express server.

Is there a way how I can avoid this problem?

Comment: Might want take a look at https://www.npmjs.com/package/express-history-api-fallback

Comment: Thank you for your support. This seems like a good solution, but I preferred the answer I marked, because it does not require an additional dependency.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can send any request to the index.html as well

This should be below your already defined express routes.

```js
router.get(['/', '/*'], function(req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "build", "index.html"));
});
```

If you want to forward anything not found in the express server you can do it like so

```js
app.use(function(req, res, next) {
 res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, "..", "..", "build", "index.html"));
});
```